# Get FFT waveform in python to match Adobe Audition Frequency Analysis

Tags: python, fft, frequency-analysis

For the wav file found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17l6fsZUm-IiTRgUpOPT0Bv4oE_I5I9tT/view?usp=sharing), I wanted to match the spectrum shown in Adobe Audition:

[image]

Currently, with the code I use:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import scipy
import scipy.fftpack
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


file1 = (r'G:/file1.wav')

fs_rate, signal = wavfile.read(file1)
print ("Frequency sampling", fs_rate)
l_audio = len(signal.shape)
print ("Channels", l_audio)
if l_audio == 2:
    signal = signal.sum(axis=1) / 2
N = signal.shape[0]
print ("Complete Samplings N", N)
secs = N / float(fs_rate)
print ("secs", secs)
Ts = 1.0/fs_rate # sampling interval in time
print ("Timestep between samples Ts", Ts)
t = np.arange(0, secs, Ts) # time vector as scipy arange field / numpy.ndarray
FFT = scipy.fftpack.fft(signal)
FFT_side = FFT[range(N//2)] # one side FFT range
freqs = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(signal.size, t[1]-t[0])
fft_freqs = np.array(freqs)
freqs_side = freqs[range(N//2)] # one side frequency range
fft_freqs_side = np.array(freqs_side)

plt.plot(freqs_side/1000, 2.0/N * abs(FFT_side))
plt.xlabel('Frequency (kHz)')
plt.ylabel('Count single-sided')

plt.show()
```

I get this plot:

[image]

Can you help me to get the plot that is just like that shown in the Adobe Audition Frequency Analysis window?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Start by changing the x axis on your plot to be logarithmic like the one from Audition

Comment: @Woodford, thanks, I added the line `plt.semilogx(freqs_side/1000, 2.0/N * abs(FFT_side))`.  The plot change a bit...how then to change this to a line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the example from [scipy.signal.welch](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html#scipy-signal-welch):

```py
fs_rate, signal = wavfile.read(file1)
f, Pxx_den = scipy.signal.welch(signal, fs_rate, nperseg=512, window='blackmanharris')
plt.semilogy(f, Pxx_den)
plt.semilogx(f, Pxx_den)
plt.xlabel('frequency [Hz]')
plt.show()
```

The y-axis units are off, but this should get you started.

[image]

Comment: for this to work, do I have to convert the wav file to mono?  I am getting the error `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (2,) and (14004, 2)`.  Thanks!